# Excel: How to pull URL data from cell inputs

Tags: excel, powerquery

I've concatenated the URL in this sheet based off of city, state, and zip code users would put in a different part of the workbook.

[image: excel url]

The table was created by going to "Data" and pulling the data "from web". Instead of manually pasting in a url everytime, can I make this pull data from the cell that's concatenated?

I tried going into "Advanced Editor" and added this, but it didn't work:

[image: advanced editor]

I was hoping if I made the URL a function it would be dynamic and the table would pull the updated cell UR. But, I'm not fluent in this language, so I'm sure I am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Define a range name in Excel as **url** and the contents of that cell would be:

```
http://www.apartmenthomeliving.com/Houston-OK/zip-code/77055-apartments
```

In powerquery,

```
let URL= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="url"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(URL)),
Data = Source{0}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data,{{"Bedroom", type text}, {"Average Rent", Currency.Type}, {"Cheapest Rent", Currency.Type}, {"Highest Rent", Currency.Type}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

In the future, when asking questions, please post code as code not as images